# How to make ::after element have same width as its previous sibling

Tags: html, css

I have an `<div>` container with an `<img>` and an `::after` pseudo-element. Like so:

```html
<div class="container" data-caption="this caption should be as wide as the image and then wrap">
  <img>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block
}
.container::after {
  display:      block
  background:   #aabbaa
  content:      attr(data-caption)
  line-height:  40px
  padding:      0 1rem
}
```

The container should get its width from the contained image while the `::after` element should wrap its content accordingly, like this:

[image]

Instead the after element does not wrap - see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/MoMolog/pen/MrZNEa).

[image]

Comment: Speaking to semantics, you probably shouldn't be using a pseudo-element for content like this. [`<figure>` and `<figcaption>`](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/) are the more appropriate choice.

Comment: @Bailey I second that. And an even more important argument is accessibility!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make image caption width to match image width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686191/how-to-make-image-caption-width-to-match-image-width)

Comment: @BaileyParker understood, thanks.

Comment: @MrLister You are absolutely right, my trial and error got me confused. Removed that part of my question.

Comment: @BaileyParker: yes, the linked answer works for my setup (using an ::after pseudo-element) as well, see here: https://codepen.io/MoMolog/pen/OzKWJB
Can / should I mark my question as a duplicate now? If so: how?

Answer (score 1):

Edited for dynamically inheriting from the image rather than the text `use max-width: min-content`:

```
.container
  display: inline-block
  border: 1px dashed red
  max-width: min-content
  &::after
    display:      block
    background:   #aabbaa
    content:      attr(data-caption)
    line-height:  40px
    padding:      0 1rem
    white-space:  wrap
```

Comment: Right, thanks. It's just that I want the image (and specifically its width) to be *variable* and *determine* the width of the whole thing.

Comment: I realized that as I was posting it that this is not the solution you were looking for and only achieved the result for the presented scenario.

Comment: I hadn't ever used min-content before but this seems like a really good use for it. :)

Comment: `min-content` is exactly what is needed to do this right. unfortunately it does not work for IE at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some positioning hacks, with a relative parent and absolute pseudo element. See here: 
https://codepen.io/palash/pen/dJabRr

Also, [`white-space: wrap` doesn't exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space), it's `white-space: normal` that you are looking for, and it's is the default value. (`nowrap` does exist, though.)

```
.container
  position: relative
  ...
  &::after
    ...
    position:     absolute
    left:         0
    right:        0
```

Edit: If you don't want to use absolute positioning (so that border comes around the caption too), you can use flexbox to do it –

Updated pen: https://codepen.io/palash/pen/BYyXjq

```
.container
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: flex-start
  width: min-content
  ...
  &::after
    background:   #aabbaa
    content:      attr(data-caption)
    line-height:  40px
    padding:      0 1rem
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the useless `white-space: wrap` rule.

The problem with this approach imho is, that the caption is "outside" the container and does not demand it's own layout space.

Comment: If you are okay with using flexbox, there's a way to do that too. Updated the answer with the code – https://codepen.io/palash/pen/BYyXjq